# How to use dagster with great expectations?

Tags: great-expectations, dagster

### The issue

I'm trying out great expectations with dagster, as per [this guide](https://docs.dagster.io/0.15.9/integrations/great-expectations)

My pipeline seems to execute correctly until it reaches this block:

```py
expectation = dagster_ge.ge_validation_op_factory(
        name='ge_validation_op',
        datasource_name='dev.data-pipeline-data-storage.data_pipelines.raw_data.sirene_update',
        suite_name='suite.data_pipelines.raw_data.sirene_update',
    )
    
if expectation["success"]:  
    print("Success")
```

trying to call `expectation["success"]` results in a

```
# TypeError: 'SolidDefinition' object is not subscriptable
```

When I go inside the code of `ge_validation_op_factory`, there is a `_ge_validation_fn` that should `yield ExpectationResult`, but somehow it gets coverted into a `SolidDefinition`...

Dagster version = 0.15.9;
Great Expectations version = 0.15.44

### Code to reproduce the error

In my code, I am trying to interact with an `s3` bucket, so it would be a bit tedious to re-create the code for my example but here it is anyway:

In a `gx_postprocessing.py`

```py
import json
import boto3
import dagster_ge
from dagster import (
    op,
    graph,
    Field,
    String,
    OpExecutionContext,
)

from typing import List, Dict


@op(
    config_schema={
        "bucket": Field(
            String,
            description="s3 bucket name",
        ),
        "path_in_s3": Field(
            String,
            description="Prefix representing the path to data",
        ),
        "technical_date": Field(
            String,
            description="date string to fetch data",
        ),
        "file_name": Field(
            String,
            description="file name that contains the data",
        ),
    }
)
def read_in_json_datafile_from_s3(context: OpExecutionContext):
    bucket = context.op_config["bucket"]
    path_in_s3 = context.op_config["path_in_s3"]
    technical_date = context.op_config["technical_date"]
    file_name = context.op_config["file_name"]

    object = f"{path_in_s3}/" f"technical_date={technical_date}/" f"{file_name}"

    s3 = boto3.resource("s3")

    content_object = s3.Object(bucket, object)
    file_content = content_object.get()["Body"].read().decode("utf-8")
    json_content = json.loads(file_content)

    return json_content


@op
def process_example_dq(data: List[Dict]):
    return len(data)


@op
def postprocess_example_dq(numrows, expectation):
    if expectation["success"]:
        return numrows
    else:
        raise ValueError


@op
def validate_example_dq(context: OpExecutionContext):

    expectation = dagster_ge.ge_validation_op_factory(
        name='ge_validation_op',
        datasource_name='my_bucket.data_pipelines.raw_data.example_update',
        suite_name='suite.data_pipelines.raw_data.example_update',
    )

    return expectation


@graph(
    config={
        "read_in_json_datafile_from_s3": {
            "config": {
                "bucket": "my_bucket",
                "path_in_s3": "my_path",
                "technical_date": "2023-01-24",
                "file_name": "myfile_20230124.json",
            }
        },
    },
)
def example_update_evaluation():
    output_dict = read_in_json_datafile_from_s3()
    nb_items = process_example_dq(data=output_dict)
    expectation = validate_example_dq()
    postprocess_example_dq(
        numrows=nb_items,
        expectation=expectation,
    )
```

Do not forget to add `great_expectations_poc_pipeline` to your `__init__.py` where the `pipelines=[..]` are listed.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, `dagster_ge.ge_validation_op_factory(...)` is returning an OpDefinition, which is the same type of thing as (for example) `process_example_dq`, and should be composed in the graph definition the same way, rather than invoked within another op.

So instead, you'd want to have something like:

```py
validate_example_dq = dagster_ge.ge_validation_op_factory(
    name='ge_validation_op',
    datasource_name='my_bucket.data_pipelines.raw_data.example_update',
    suite_name='suite.data_pipelines.raw_data.example_update',
)
```

Then use that op inside your graph definition the same way you currently are (i.e. `expectation = validate_example_dq()`)